# C#: check if file exists - process cannot access file error

Tags: c#, xml, file-exists

I'm learning c# right now and I want to check if file exists. If it exists it should load and write an xml file. If it doesn't exists it should create it and after that it should load and write the xml file. But if I click my button, there comes an error:

"The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process."

Here you can see my code:

```
private void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    XElement xmlnode = new XElement("Namespace",
            new XElement("RandomText1", textBox1.Text),
            new XElement("RandomText2", textBox2.Text),
            new XElement("RandomText3", textBox3.Text)
    );

    XElement xmlFile;
    try
    {
        xmlFile = XElement.Load("testsave.xml");
        xmlFile.Add(xmlnode);
    }
    catch (XmlException)
    {
        xmlFile = new XElement("Test", xmlnode);
    }

    xmlFile.Save("testsave.xml");
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    ds.ReadXml("testsave.xml");
    DataTable dt = ds.Tables[0];
    dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
}

private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!File.Exists("testsave.xml"))
    {
        File.Create("testsave.xml");
    }
}
```

Comment: Close the FileStream returned by File.Create().

Comment: Why do you check for/create the xml file in `Form1_Load` instead of in `btnSave_Click` right before the `try/catch`?

Comment: That's another idea. What's the difference? Every hint is welcome because I'm learning :)

Comment: When you write software, sometimes it's good to be lazy. Only do stuff, when you *have to*. Do you *have to* make sure the file exists when you open the form? Does anything else depend on that, or is it just that one button? What if someone opens the form but doesn't press the button? Then the file might be created unnecessarily. Also, you don't even have to create it like that. `xmlFile.Save("...")` will create it if it's not there, so you just need to check for it's presence to know if you should try loading it.

Comment: And a last thing, there is an overload of the [DataSet.ReadXml](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/360dye2a.aspx) that takes a string. You already have the complete content of `testsave.xml` in the `xmlFile` variable. So there is no need to go the long (and slow) way and retrieve that data from disk where you just saved it to, when you can just pass it like `ds.ReadXml(xmlFile.ToString());`.

Comment: Okay, thank you :) That makes sense to create the file only if someone clicks the button. Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Problem is `File.Create` creates a file and returns you the `FileStream` opened. So when you're trying to access it later you get exception. You've to close it prior to use it later.

Try this

```
using (File.Create("testsave.xml"))
{ }
```

Or

```
File.Create("testsave.xml").Close();
```

Comment: aaaah nice! Thank you very much :) sounds logical :)

Answer (score 0):

This error happens if you open that file in another program. Close it if you have opened it in other programs and run your app again

Comment: I just open in it VS2012 for debugging and nowhere else